# how to load the .vue files of a vue project with node.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, command-line-interface, vuejs2, babeljs

I want to analize the current router config of my project with vue2. Because I wanna use cli to generate a vue component. Before that I have to load current route register info. But when I require router.js under my router directory. Node throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. I try many ways to fix it but they didn't work. Please tell me the right way to load my router config. Thanks!

```
    //to load router config
    const routerPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', 'router', 'index.js');

    if (existsSync(routerPath)) {
        routes = require(routerPath)
    }

    //error
    import Vue from "vue";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at Object. (/Users/mosx/projects/mjb-cli/lib/check-components.js:28:33)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object. (/Users/mosx/projects/mjb-cli/bin/mjb-component:12:25)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

    // path/to/router/index.js
    import Router from "vue-router";
    import Hello from "../components/Hello.vue";

    Vue.use(Router);

    export default new Router({
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/',
                name: 'Hello',
                component: Hello,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'child',
                        name: 'child',
                        component: Hello
                    }
                ]
            }

        ]
    })
```

Comment: please post the code related to this question

Comment: @divine, sorry for no code before, now I added it

Answer (score 1):

Though the modularity of the code posted in the question is questionable, 
i believe my answer would solve the problem you are facing. 
Here it goes..

To build the below code, i made use of vue boilerplate

```
vue init webpack-simple vue-cli
```

Then, i installed vue-router package

```
npm install --save vue-router
```

**Main.js File**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {routes} from './routes';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes : routes,
  mode : 'history'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router : router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**Route.js file**

```
import Cricket from './components/Cricket.vue';
import Football from './components/Football.vue';
import Basketball from './components/Basketball.vue';
import Sports from './components/Sports.vue';
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/cricket',
        component: Cricket
    },
    {
        path: '/football',
        component: Football
    },
    {
        path: '/basketball',
        component: Basketball
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: Sports
    }
];
```